# Mercedes 2.7CDI C Class 2004 Hard Starts

Tags: fuel-system, starting, mercedes-benz

My 2004 2.7CDI gives me a hard start when I am starting it the first time in the morning after parking it over night it but works and starts perfectly thereafter till the next morning. The fault does not show on the dash board or on diagnostic machines.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem for when your glow plugs are wearing out, or not heating as they should. If they are not heating properly, but are still heating, you'll not get an error code. Getting them replaced would be the first thing I'd look at doing.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess on this would be Glow/Heater plugs or the circuit wiring or relay, but since you say it's not showing on diagnostic checks it would lead me to believe it's a mechanical failure. Have you had a compression test done? That would be my next move.